# Get the first word of a string in Angular using a Pipe?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm trying to write a pipe that prints the `first word` in a string. Following is my erroneous code that undesirably prints the `first letter` of a string.

For eg.

**`PIPE`**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'firstWord'
})
export class GetFirstWord implements PipeTransform
{
    transform(value: string, args: any[]): string | boolean
    {
        if (value === null) {return false;}
        const firstWords = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        {
          const words = value[i].split(' ');
          firstWords.push(words[0]);
        }
        return firstWords[0];
    }
}
```

**`COMPONENT`**

```
userName: string = 'Chuck Norris';
```

**`TEMPLATE`**

```
{{ userName | firstWord }}
```

**`OUTPUT`**

> C

**`DESIRED OUTPUT`**

> Chuck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a loop

```
transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
  if (!value) { return ''; }
  return value.split(' ')[0];
}
```

Comment: No way I could have missed something as easy as this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Yury . you downvoted. i can see it as you lost 2 points. !! any specific reason for downvoting?

Comment: @Aravind I didn't Sherlock :) If it was me I'd lost 1 point LOL. And I always comment when downvote (just my personal rule). Someone downvoted my answer as well

Comment: All solutions work perfectly but I accept this answer as it was the quickest.

Answer (score 4):

That's because your for loop goes on the characters of the string. You should split the whole input instead and get the first occurrence.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'firstWord'
})
export class GetFirstWord implements PipeTransform
{
    transform(value: string, args: any[]): string | boolean
    {
        if (value == null) {
          return value;
        }
        const words = value.split(' ');
        return words.length > 0 ? words[0] : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you. :) By the way I suggest you to return with strings only in pipes otherwise you can see interesting thing when you want to debug your code. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for case like , 
userName: string = '   Chuck Norris  ';
unwanted spaces before the first word

```
export class firstWord implements PipeTransform{

transform(value: string): string {
   if (!value) { return value; }
   value=value.trim();      
   return value.split(' ')[0];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in angular 2+ without any pipe in HTML file (template interpolation) by the following way

```
{{ object_or_paragraph.split(' ')[0]  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way

```
 transform(input:string):string{

     return input.split(' ')[0];
    }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/l31C4Ybfjc2HEQ3GVbcf?p=preview)**

Comment: @anonym happy to help you.

Comment: @anonym what is that reason?

Comment: I guess your indentation or the useless `console.log()` that you deleted later, or maybe it's just a jealous serial downvoter, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(value: string): string | boolean {
    if (value) {
      return value.split(' ')[0];
    }
    return false;
  }
```